# How many season I can play in manager mode?

Tags: fifa-10

I'm in the 6th season of manager mode in FIFA 10.

Does manager mode have a limited amount of seasons? And if so: how many seasons can I play?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like that manager mode lasts for 15 seasons.

Sources:

[Yahoo Answer 1](http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101118081720AAFX6yn)

[Yahoo Answer 2](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091228020143AAPY2wO)

[EA Forum (German)](http://forum.ea.com/de/posts/list/12381.page)

Answer (score 0):

The Manager Mode for fifa 10 lasts for 15 seasons as you can also see it in **>TEAM MANAGEMENT >PLAYER GROWTH> -/+<> .**